# multiple crontab jobs but only one of them should not send email

Tags: linux, email, unix, cron

I know that crontab job emails output of the job to its user. In my crontab file I have multiple jobs like:

```
10 21 * * * test1.sh
13 21 * * * test2.sh
0 * * * * test3.sh
```

I don't want to receive email for test3.sh. Does below code works? I want to make sure that only for the last job I wont receive email.

```
10 21 * * * test1.sh
13 21 * * * test2.sh
MAILTO=""
0 * * * * test3.sh
```

Comment: Why don't you simply try out the second crontab?

Comment: some critical jobs are running there

Comment: You should always test such things locally, for example on a virtual machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/disable-the-mail-alert-by-crontab-command/

You could use something like

```
0 * * * * test3.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

There will be no output --> no mail sent.